# How can we use custom setpoints in CEP

Tags: cumulocity

I want to create a dashboard or maybe widgets where a user can add custom setpoints.
These setpoints should be stored for later use creating streaming analytics with CEP.

What would be the (best) approach for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If these setpoints are related to a device a good approach would be to store them in the device object.
Maybe have a dedicated fragment in the device that is managed by your dashboard widget that will allow the configuration of these setpoints.

From CEP you then can check those fragments by querying the device

Comment: Hi, 

so we have added a fragment  but we do not know how to query on this in the device in CEP.

I added the fragments through the command Insert into UpdateManagedObject.

We need to use it in the calculations in CEP modules.

Can you point us in the right direction with documentation of Cumulocity or maybe a snippet of a query.